# Implementing PARSE & MIXPANEL on an Android mobile app

Tags: android, mobile, push-notification, parse-platform, mixpanel

We need to implement both Parse and Mixpanel in our Android mobile app. Parse will be used for our push notifications and Mixpanel for the analytics+Push notifications in some cases.

We are having some issues implementing both, however, it worked just fine on iOS. 
On android we seem unable to register multiple broadcast receivers to receive PUSH notifications from both MixPanel and Parse. Has anyone ever done this? Any tips would be greatly appreciated since I'm unable to find any related topic anywhere!

Cheers

Comment: Please post the issues you are having.

Answer (score -3):

> We need to implement both Parse and Mixpanel in our Android mobile
>   app. Parse will be used for our push notifications and Mixpanel for
>   the analytics+Push notifications in some cases.

Why are you trying to mix both the APIs when Parse offers the `Parse Analytics` API? The Parse Analytics API will allow you to track:

App usage

Push Notifications

Growth Analytics

Any other custom analytics

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Look at the OPs question. What else can I answer? They are having "problems". What problems are they having? No clue.

Comment: Then you should state that in a comment so the OP can provide more information about their problem

Comment: Apologies folks, edited the question to give more info

Comment: @Chimele WHy not just stick to Parse? :) or MixPanel?

Comment: started by implementing parse for the push notifications and now need more in depth detail about analytics (funnels, people analytics...) makes sense to you?